# CMake Error at cmake/modules/Findasio.cmake:11 - Failed to locate ASIO dependency

Tags: visual-studio-2015, cmake, boost-asio, restbed

I'm trying to use the [`restbed framework`](https://github.com/Corvusoft/restbed) in a visual studio 2015 project.

I cloned the restbed repo: https://github.com/Corvusoft/restbed.git

And to create a Visual studio project file I'm using current [cmake 3.8.1](https://cmake.org/download/) version

Now, when trying to configure restbed with cmake, I got this error:

```
  Copyright 2013-2017, Corvusoft Ltd, All Rights Reserved.
CMake Error at cmake/modules/Findasio.cmake:11 (message):
  Failed to locate ASIO dependency.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:31 (find_package)
```

**Is there a way how to solve this Asio problem ?**

Right now I'm trying to compile [Boost library](http://www.boost.org/) to see where to find and add these Asio dependencies to Cmake.

Content of **CMakeLists.txt** file for restbed:

```
line
26   #
27   # Dependencies
28   #
29   set( CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/modules" )
30 
31   find_package( asio REQUIRED )
32   include_directories( SYSTEM ${asio_INCLUDE} )
```

**CMake (configure) output:**

```
The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24215.1
Check for working CXX compiler: F:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual 
Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe
Check for working CXX compiler: F:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual 
Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe -- works
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Detecting CXX compile features
Detecting CXX compile features - done
   Copyright 2013-2017, Corvusoft Ltd, All Rights Reserved.
CMake Error at cmake/modules/Findasio.cmake:11 (message):
  Failed to locate ASIO dependency.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:31 (find_package)

Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/xxx/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/thread_Native_Handle/resbed_windows/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asio (not to be confused with boost asio) is [included](https://github.com/Corvusoft/restbed/tree/master/dependency) in the restbed repository as a Git submodule.  CMake should automatically find Asio's headers when it is first run.  You probably forgot to run `git submodule init` and `git submodule update` after cloning the project.  Run those commands in the directory where you cloned restbed, and the build should start working.

If you did need to point restbed to a specific asio installation, per [this file](https://github.com/Corvusoft/restbed/blob/master/cmake/modules/Findasio.cmake), just set the CMake variable `asio_INCLUDE` to the directory containing `asio.hpp`.

Comment: Thanks ! Usefull info when you are not coming from the C world

Answer (score 1):

Have you followed the instructions stated within the ReadMe?

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/corvusoft/restbed.git
mkdir restbed/build
cd restbed/build
cmake [-DBUILD_TESTS=YES] [-DBUILD_EXAMPLES=YES] [-DBUILD_SSL=NO] [-DBUILD_SHARED=YES] [-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/output-directory] ..
make [-j CPU_CORES+1] install
make test
```

Comment: I'm using cmake 3.8.1 under windows, **@MultipleMonomials answer solved the problem for ASIO**, now I'm trying to solve this problem: `CMake Error at cmake/modules/Findopenssl.cmake:19 (message):
  Failed to locate OpenSSL dependency.  see restbed/dependency/openssl;
  ./config shared; make all
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:38 (find_package)`

Comment: git clone --recursive will perform a submodule init and update in one command. Please make sure you have performed this action.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because asio library is not installed.

Download, build and install asio library from https://think-async.com/Asio/

```
./configure --without-boost
make
sudo make install
```

Then download [restbed](https://github.com/Corvusoft/restbed) and build

```
git clone https://github.com/Corvusoft/restbed.git
mkdir restbed/build
cd restbed/build
cmake -D BUILD_SSL=OFF -D BUILD_TESTS=OFF -D BUILD_STATIC=ON -D BUILD_SHARED=OFF ..
make
make install
```